# How do I keep default highlight and click properties for Custom Button in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, button

I 've created a custom style for my Button, but it is no longer clickable, how do I keep the default click properties for the button.

```
 <Style x:Key="customStyle" TargetType="Button">   
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,1,1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Canvas x:Name="ButtonCanvas" Width="171" Height="144">
                    <Image x:Name="ButtonImage" Width="171" Height="144" Source="{Binding thumbnail}"/>
                </Canvas>             
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Do you mean that no click event is raised when you click it or that you don't get any visual feedback?

Comment: @Meleak I don't get any visual feedback.

Comment: @Meleak, is there a way to keep the default properties, so I don't have to manually set them again in my custom template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have provided a custom template, that contains none of the visual states normally associated with a button (e.g. Pressed, Disabled, ...)

The best you can do is use Expression Blend, which allows you to cutomize the standard template easily. Alternatively , you can start from the default template available at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328(v=vs.100).aspx.